# Opening VSTO project in Visual studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2015, vsto

There is one project which is originally created on Visual Studio 2010 and its a VSTO Word Addin project few years back

Now for maintenance i have to work on same project but only Visual Studio 2015 is available on my machine and its showing alert Cannot open this project.

So how can i upgrade  this solution so that i can open my project in VS 2015

The error message now i am getting while trying to open the project in Visual Studio 2015 is

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's late, but hopefully solution could help somebody else.

You need to create new project of the same type. Then open the new project file (first unload the project and right click to edit `.csproj` file).

Next replace section `<VisualStudio>` in your old project with content from the newly created one. Then reload your old project and everything should work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to download "Microsoft Office Developer Tools" for Visual Studio 2015. I just downloaded them from this link:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=51683&6B49FDFB-8E5B-4B07-BC31-15695C5A2143=1